# Nokogiri in Rails - Scrape results of multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri in Rails while attempting to get the results from multiple pages of a Subreddit but I can only get the first page. Any ideas on how to acheive this. I can't seem to figure this out. Here's my current RedditScraper class:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class RedditScraper

def initialize
 @headline = []
end

def fetch_reddit_headlines
 page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby"))
 page.css('a.title').each do |link|
   if link['href'].include?('http')
    @headline << { content: link.content, href: link['href'] }
   else
    @headline << { content: link.content, href: "http://reddit.com" + link['href'] }
   end
  end
  @headline
 end
end
```

**JUST ADDED**

Controller method:

```
def index
 @fetch_reddit = RedditScraper.new.fetch_reddit_headlines    
end
```

View code:

```
<ol>
 <% @fetch_reddit.each do |url| %>
  <li><%= link_to url[:content], url[:href], target: '_' %></li>
 <% end %>
</ol>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) with Nokogiri, you could click on the next page link by doing something like this:

**Update: Fixed some bugs**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'


class RedditScraper

  def initialize
    @headline = []
    @agent = Mechanize.new
  end

  def fetch_reddit_headlines
    mech_page = @agent.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby')

    num_pages_to_scrape = 10
    count = 0

    while(num_pages_to_scrape > count)
      page = mech_page.parser

      page.css('a.title').each do |link|
        if link['href'].include?('http')
          @headline << { content: link.content, href: link['href'] }
        else
          @headline << { content: link.content, href: "http://reddit.com" + link['href'] }
        end
      end
      @headline

      count += 1
      mech_page = @agent.get(page.css('.nextprev').css('a').last.attributes["href"].value)
    end

    return @headline
  end
end


r = RedditScraper.new
r.fetch_reddit_headlines
puts r.instance_variable_get(:@headline)
puts r.instance_variable_get(:@headline).count
```

Comment: I tried the code, but now getting the message above (See updated question)

Comment: @Chip - I updated my code. Just needed to return the `@headline` variable at the end of the function. Look at the bottom of `fetch_reddit_headlines`

Comment: @Chip You may want to store the headlines in a database record. It will be a lot faster than scraping the webpage for every request. Let me know if you need help doing that :)

Comment: Thanks Matt. How would I store them in a db record? I'm using pg.

Comment: @Chip - Shoot me an email at mattleonardco@gmail.com and we can discuss there. Need some more info on your app.

Comment: I emailed you the info.